# How to export an Electron App integrated with React for different platforms?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

## Installations

I've create my react app with:

```
npx create-react-app testing_app --typescript
```

Then I install these dependencies:

```
npm install --save cross-env electron-is-dev
npm install concurrently electron electron-builder wait-on
```

Then I create an `electron.js` file in the public directory:

```js
const electron = require("electron");
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const path = require("path");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 900, height: 680 });
    mainWindow.loadURL(isDev ? "http://localhost:3000": 
        `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`);

    mainWindow.on("closed", () => (mainWindow = null));
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

And these is how my `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "testing_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Some Description",
  "author": "Emma",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.testing_app"
  },
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "concurrently": "^7.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^18.2.0",
    "electron-builder": "^23.0.3",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "react-start": "react-scripts start",
    "react-build": "react-scripts build",
    "react-test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "react-eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-build": "electron-builder",
    "release": "npm run build && electron-builder --linux --win --mac --x64 --ia32 --publish never",
    "build": "npm run react-build && npm run electron-build",
    "start": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

## Commands I've tried

I've tried with

```
npm run build && electron-builder --linux --win --mac --x64 --ia32 --publish never
```

But this error happend:

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBv6e.png)

Comment: Did you try to execute by moving the `electron` modules to `devdependencies` from your error screenshot?

Comment: Thanks I use `npm install electron-builder --save` It works once I've set the `npm run build && electron-builder --linux --win --mac --x64 --ia32 --publish never` but just make the macOS version not the windows on linux version

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, you have to remove the

```json
    "electron": "^18.2.0",
    "electron-builder": "^23.0.3",
```

lines in your package.json file.